# 550 5.7.1 Your email messages have been blocked by the recipient OR by Trend Micro Email Reputation Service

Tags: email, pop3, email-bounces, anti-virus

I have an email account with POP3 connection and I am having a problem sending emails when I'm out of the office.

I keep getting this email error message "550 5.7.1 Your email messages have been blocked by the recipient OR by Trend Micro Email Reputation Service"

We are using Trend Micro Worry Free Security Software in the office, I have seen that I can add an IP to the Email Reputation Service within Trend Micro which will approve my IP, but this doesn't work and I have done a test to see if this is a problem with trend by turning off the trend messaging master service. When this is off email will send.

I have also checked http://www.mail-abuse.com/lookup.html and our IP doesn't appear.

I have rang Trend Micro and all they can say at the moment is their working on it.

If anyone has solved this problem or has any experience with this problem please could I have some advice

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the remote host.They are more than likely using Trend Micro's own block lists. If you have access to a smarthost (IE your ISP) try sending it via that instead.